# ionic 2 refresh view

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

in Ionic how app can automatic refresh view when location is enabled.

this is my code

```
this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
            diagnostic.isLocationAvailable().then(
              (isAvailable) => {
                console.log('Is available? ' + isAvailable);
                this.location.getPostion();
                this.location.getCity(location.lat, location.lng);
              }).catch( (err) => {
                console.log(err);
                console.log("Please enable your location");
              });                  
          });
```

If location is not enabled when app starts I must kill app and then turn location on, start app again to get position. How it can be changed automatic in background, when I turn location on, app refresh view and display position

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have mistaken your requirements, you want to start tracking a user's location upon it becoming available (but it's switched off originally, and the only way to retrigger it is after you have enabled it).

**Reason**

`this.platform.ready()` is only called once assuming it is in `app.component` (which is the default location for it). Therefore, that fires at the beginning of the app, and I expect `diagnostic.isLocationAvailable()` resolves to false, or is rejected.

As a result, there's no way to retrigger said code unless you enable a button click.

**Solution**

```
watchPosition()
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/#watchPosition

> Watch the current device’s position. Clear the watch by unsubscribing from Observable changes.

However, I am not sure whether this will run if position is disabled. If you watch the position, you can unsubscribe after getting the first ping:

```
const subscription = this.geolocation.watchPosition()
  .filter((p) => p.coords !== undefined) //Filter Out Errors
  .subscribe(position => {
    console.log(position.coords.longitude + ' ' + position.coords.latitude);
    subscription.unsubsribe();
  });
```

I am not sure what happens if location is physically disabled. But I do not believe there's a listener for that.